# Creating OR tools layer for AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, pip, or-tools, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to run OR-Tools on Lambda to solve the travelling salesman problem. I'm using a Python 3.9 runtime. I created a lambda layer in the usual way:

```
mkdir python
cd python
pip3 install ortools -t .
```

Then I zipped the parent folder and the final zip structure is

ortools-layer -> python -> all the ortools files

However when I try to execute the lambda function I get the CloudWatch error:

```
[ERROR] ImportError: cannot import name '_pywrapcp' from 'ortools.constraint_solver' (/opt/python/ortools/constraint_solver/__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/serverless_aws_lambda_sdk/instrument/__init__.py", line 596, in stub
    return self._handler(user_handler, event, context)
  File "/opt/python/serverless_aws_lambda_sdk/instrument/__init__.py", line 578, in _handler
    result = user_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/serverless_sdk/__init__.py", line 144, in wrapped_handler
    return user_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/s_writeSortedToS3ORTools.py", line 25, in error_handler
    raise e
  File "/var/task/s_writeSortedToS3ORTools.py", line 20, in <module>
    user_handler = serverless_sdk.get_user_handler('writeSortedToS3ORTools.writeSortedToS3ORTools')
  File "/var/task/serverless_sdk/__init__.py", line 56, in get_user_handler
    user_module = import_module(user_module_name)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/writeSortedToS3ORTools.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
  File "/opt/python/ortools/constraint_solver/pywrapcp.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import _pywrapcp
```

Is there an easy fix for this? I found some threads that mention using Docker/EC2 instances but I am deploying my lambdas using the Serverless Framework, and only providing a reference to a lambda layer uploaded separately to S3. The existing solutions seem to be complicated and/or involve situations where the lambda function is written/deployed from the same place as the layers/dependencies.

Is there an easy way to change my layer to solve the import problem?

Tried to find solutions online, found references to installing VSCode redistrubutable (don't think that is possible on lambda) and some Docker scripts etc.

I would like to know if the standard layer creating procedure:

```
mkdir python
cd python
pip3 install ortools -t .
```

can be modified in some way to create a layer that is usable.

Comment: VSCode Redistributable is for the windows native python package, I'm pretty sure aws lambda are based on unix (linux?) distro OS...

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a specific solution to your problem, but I think that you should be using [Lambda container images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) to install OR-Tools into the Lambda function. Zipping the pip-installed packages is unlikely to work for various reasons.

For what it's worth, moving from local development to production with Python models can be nontrivial. This is why we built [an OR-Tools integration](https://www.nextmv.io/blog/the-nextmv-or-tools-integration-quickly-deploy-and-test-or-tools-models) at Nextmv.